# Assertion error in Ember-data has many relationship

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data

I am new to defining relationships in ember. Please help me on this.

This is how i am having relationships.

```
 App.Post= DS.Model.extend({

     comment: DS.belongsTo('comment'),
     name:     DS.attr('string')
 });

 App.Comment =DS.Model.extend({

    post: DS.belongsTo('Post'),
    value:   DS.attr('string')
 });

 App.PostSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
       comments: {embedded: 'always'}
    }
 });
```

Saving Post model:

```
        var model = this.store.createRecord('post');

        model.get('comments').pushObject(this.store.createRecord('comment'));


        model.setProperties({
            name: 'test'
        });

        model.save();
```

Whenever i am trying to save post model, i am getting the following error:

Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an `id` for App.Comment in an object passed to `push`

I may be wrong on using embedded records. Please help me out on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We implement hasMany via a tabel that connects two parts together.
For your example it would look like this.

```
App.Post= DS.Model.extend({
     name:     DS.attr('string')
 });

 App.Comment =DS.Model.extend({
    value:   DS.attr('string')
});

 App.CommentPost = DS.Model.extend({
   post: DS.belongsTo('post'),
   comment: DS.belongsTo('comment')
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Kristjan..is there any way i can achieve with the same stuff i have posted??

Comment: @user3139250 I dont think so, because databases are structured like: Post, Comment, CommentPost. Maybe there is a way, but this is unusual.